# Out of memory when open a golden xlsm file

Tags: excel, vba

I added few VBA code in my workbook (myworkbook.xlsm) for the function :
when my workbook is opened, the VBA code will copy one sheet from the golden workbook (golden.xlsm).
I added the Sub Workbook_Open into the object "ThisWorkbook" of myworkbook.xlsm, the copy is successful. But the issue is when I use "Alt+F11" to open the Visual Basic editor, there will be a message box to complain "Out of memory", and I can't edit my other VBA code anymore.

I try to comment out some code in the `Workbook_Open` handler, the following line will lead to this issue :

```
Set goldenWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("golden.xlsm")
```

My code added for the open event of object "ThisWorkbook"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim goldenWorkbook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Debug.Print "Hello~you just open the file"
    Set goldenWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("golden.xlsm")
    goldenWorkbook.Sheets("Common").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    goldenWorkbook.Close True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set goldenWorkbook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does `golden.xlsm` have a `Workbook_Open` as well?

Comment: No, there are some macros inside golden.xlsm, but no one named as Workbook_Open.

Comment: When I remove the macros inside golden.xlsm, no "out of memory" anymore. the two files have duplicated macros. It seems not easy to debug..

Comment: Are there any macros in the sheet module of the sheet being copied?

Comment: no macros for the sheet objects.

Comment: Can you try by writing full path to the file `golden.xlsm`.

Comment: yes, I already have full path for the file in my code.